# Connections drop during a rolling update of Kubernetes pod running a Dropwizard app

Tags: kubernetes, dropwizard, kubernetes-helm

A good number of connections drop during a rolling update of Kubernetes pod running a Dropwizard app.

I updated the Dropwizard `shutdownGracePeriod` and Kubernetes `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` values to 60s and 90s respectively (defaults being 30s and 60s resp.) and I didn't see any difference in the results. Any suggestions on this as I'm trying to achieve minimal downtime during the upgrade.

Comment: Have you tried to check what happens during an upgrade? Does it actually perform a Rolling upgrade? Otherwise you could look into configuring the RollingUpdateStrategy if it turns out it is not doing what you want.

Comment: How many nodes/pods are you running? Did you tried adjusting maxSurge and maxUnavailable fields?

Comment: @Blokje5 - Yes, it's performing a rolling upgrade.

Comment: @PrateekJain - 1 node, 1 pod. I used the defaults for the rolling update:
`maxSurge: 1
 maxUnavailable: 0
 maxUnavailable: 25%`

Comment: I dont think rolling update is effective here. I expect you are loosing that active pod first and then only new pod is coming online. you can watch sequence of events happening in cluster by 'kubectl get events --watch'.

Comment: @PrateekJain - I checked the events log so not quite. Once the new pod is up and running, the older pod is terminated.

`<invalid>   Normal   Pulled   Pod   Successfully pulled image "xxxxx"
<invalid>   Normal   Created   Pod   Created container
<invalid>   Normal   Started   Pod   Started container
<invalid>   Normal   ScalingReplicaSet   Deployment   Scaled down replica set xxxxx-728b6bf659 to 0
<invalid>   Normal   SuccessfulDelete   ReplicaSet   Deleted pod: xxxxx-728b6bf659-asda12
<invalid>   Normal   Killing   Pod   Killing container with id docker://xxxxx:Need to kill Pod`

Comment: Do you have readinessProbe configured and working properly?

Comment: Yes, I do and it's working properly.